# I can't log in as admin

Tags: php

i have created a login system where i can login as a admin, or as a user (employer). If i'm logged in as a admin, on the next page i can update, delete or create a new employer, and if i'm logged in as a employer a didn't have that options. This works fine, but today when i'm logged in as admin a don't have that permission and i got a message: You can't create a new user (this is the message that i have posted in else statement).

This is my homepage.php script. Any help?

```
<?php

    require_once("connection.php");

    $user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $role = $_SESSION['role'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);


    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo $role ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <?php if($role == 'admin') { ?>

        <a href="new_emp.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">New Employee</button></a>
      <?php } else { }?>
        <a href="info.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Employee</button></a>
        <a href="logout.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign Out</button></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table bordered" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:250px">UserName</th>
                        <th style="width:250px">User Password</th>
                        <th style="width:250px">User Role</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($stmt as $row){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></td>
                        <td>*******</td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_role'] ?></td>
                        <?php if($role == "admin"){ ?>
                        <td>
                            <form action="delete.php" name="deleteForm" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>"/>
                                <button type="submit" name="delete_user" class="btn btn-info">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="update.php" name="updForm" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="update_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>"/>
                                <button type="submit" name="update_user" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($role == "admin"){ ?>
                    <form action="add_user.php" method="POST" name="add_user">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="password" class="form-control"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="select_role" class="form-control">
                                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                <option value="emp">Employee</option>
                            </selet>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" name="sub_user" class="btn btn-danger">Add User</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } else{ ?>
                    <tr>
                        You can't add a new user!
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </form>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If the code in your `else` statement is executing, then clearly the condition in the `if` statement is false.  What has your debugging revealed?

Comment: So what does `$role` actually contain?

Comment: You only set `$role` from the session. If `$_SESSION['role']` is the one that contains the wrong value, we need to see where and how you set it. This is just how you use it after it already contains the wrong value.

Comment: $role contains the user_role row at the database. After i debug $role it says "admin" so i think that's ok.

Comment: This is my connection script where i'm sets the if statement for userid and role. 
<?php
 session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['userid']) && !isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
   header("Location: php_page.php");
  }else{
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_name = "phpcourse";
 
 $db_user = 'root';

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  }

?>

Comment: Don't add extra code as a comment! Update your question instead! As you can see, it's unreadable...

Comment: You need to echo $role to find out what it's passing first then post back.

Comment: The echo is passing admin.

Answer (score 1):

where is `session_start();`
 function because without this function how can you get the session variables so please first put the session_start() at top of the file and then check.

Comment: Check my latest reply, it's in my connection.php file.